# read ALL response headers of ajax GET request of S3 objects

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Question Overview:**
I am accessing a list of files stored in my AWS S3 bucket through a CORS request of presigned files. This basically works fine. However, the objects have some custom METADATA attached to them, which I can't access. I understood, that I can access this metadata only when I add the header key (e.g. "x-amz-meta-1234", where 1234 is the key of my metadata) to the Expose-Headers of the target-bucket's CORS config. While this works so far for me, I can't set the expose-header with a wildcard (e.g. "x-amz-meta-*"), which would solve my problem, but AWS doesn't support wildcards for the expose-header entries.

However, when I look in the NETWORK tab of my Chrome Dev Tools, all desired metadata is showing up in the headers during the GET/HEAD request (note the entries on the lower part, x-amz-meta-4021 and -template_id):
[image: response headers of request in chrome]

This is my HEAD call:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: url,                      
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true,
                type: 'HEAD',
                success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                    console.log('got some response ..?');
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log('responseHeader template_id: ' + jqXHR.getResponseHeader('x-amz-meta-template_id'));
                    console.log('responseHeader meta-4021: ' + jqXHR.getResponseHeader('x-amz-meta-4021'));
                    console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
                },
                error: function(error, xhr, data) {
                    console.log('in error..');
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

And this is the console output:

```
Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: 
function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
responseHeader template_id: 813
responseHeader meta-4021: null
x-amz-meta-template_id: 813
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Jun 2017 13:05:33 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

I set expose-header for the metadata-entry 'template_id' explicitly and therefore the header-data is returned correctly for this entry. However, for the entry '4021' I didn't set the expose-header. The problem is, that this metadata (and the keys) are produced by our (android/ios) apps, and I can't really control the keys of that metadata that easily.

**Whats puzzling me**: why am I able to see the whole response in the chrome network tab, but can't access this data from a client-side script? There are many possible workarounds and solutions, but I basically want to understand, why my browser can display me data, which can't be accessed by jQuery.

PS: in case you want to see the CORS config or the full script, please let me know. I tried to be as precise as possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution to how to fetch 'etag' value from response header? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Recently I worked with MINIO (similar capabilities like AWS S3), and iirc fetching the ETAG value was not possible like in my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I basically want to understand, why my browser can display me data, which can't be accessed by jQuery.

To understand this, you need to understand the purpose of CORS.

CORS isn't really about access control, and CORS isn't really working on your site's behalf.  CORS is working on behalf of the user and the browser, to prevent the browser from becoming a [confused deputy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem) and doing something the user would not have wanted.  This usually coincides with something the site would also not have wanted, but that's secondary.

The browser's default behavior is to assume that programmatic access to cross-origin requests is bad, which is why they are denied when no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present.  Your bank would not want internetbadguys.com to make ajax requests to the bank web site, and if that site tried, the browser would block it unless the bank's web server foolishly allowed it with a CORS response.

CORS is a mechanism for your site to tell the brower, "yes, the cross-origin request you are making is not unexpected, it's allowed... and from this response, the browser is allowed to engage in certain behaviors, such as exposing the following response headers to the code making the request."

In that light, the behavior you observe is correct.  Exposing headers (or not) doesn't mean include them in the HTTP response (or not) -- exposing headers gives the browser permission to expose what it knows to the ajax caller.  If the cross-origin origin wants them exposed, it has to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information! "Exposing headers (or not) doesn't mean include them in the HTTP response" - in this case I simply observed the behaviour, but I understand the point you are making. In short, I will need to let the metadata be defined in a less-generic way (without going too much into detail for this question) or find another mechanism to store my metadata. I will mark your reply as the ANSWER in 1-2 days, maybe some other interesting points will come up.

Comment: If your entire application as well as the bucket were both configured behind a single CloudFront distribution (the bucket, receiving all requests for one path prefix, for example, `/media/*`, and the app receiving requests for any other path) and your hostname pointed to CloudFront, the requests would no longer be cross-origin (they'd be same-origin) and the issue goes away.  You'd need to use CloudFront signed URLs instead of S3 (different algorithm), but then you'd also benefit from edge-caching of responses near the app users.